# Oracle revoke CLOB space

Tags: oracle, clob

I have a tablespace 175G, there is a table with a clob column.
Now the clob column has been increased to 115G.
It takes bad effect on my database.
I want to clean the column now, how can I do it ? And I need to keep
my system working during the whole process.

Thank you !

Best Regards
Sugaryu

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <clob_column> = EMPTY_CLOB();
COMMIT;
```

Just make sure you check with the business or users of your system that the clob column is about to be cleaned!

Comment: Thanks for your help. And I want to know if the empty_clob() can release the storage ?

Comment: Not sure if this works: ALTER TABLE <table> MODIFY LOB <clob_column> (SHRINK SPACE);

Comment: Personally, I would look into online reorgs using DBMS_REDEFINITION, considering that your system cannot be taken down.